# Организация данных бд

Tags: организация, php, база-данных, sql

Здравствуйте.

Хочу понять, как организовывается система поддержки между сайтами, а точнее как обрабатывать и получать их можно, давать ответ.

Допустим, есть у нас три сайта, на них по 3 бд.  На каждом сайте форма для создания сообщения. Как сделать, чтобы при создании сообщения на этих сайтах можно было их собирать вместе и отвечать на них, чтоб ответы потом были на этих сайтах? Может, кто поделится информацией, как сделать такое, сделать, чтобы все сообщения записывались в другую бд и в ней хранились, а оттуда запрос посылать на сайты, или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Прямое подключение к БД. Пишите веб-морду, с которой подключаетесь к 3 БД.

```
$link1=mysql_connect("host1","user1","");
    mysql_select_db("db1");
$link2=mysql_connect("host2","user2","");
    mysql_select_db("db2",$link2);
...
$linkN=mysql_connect("hostN","userN","");
    mysql_select_db("dbN",$linkN);
```

При обращении к таблицам указываете ключ-название БД:

```
select * from `db1`.`table_message`
```

Метод сложноват в управлении, так как при изменении количества БД, параметров доступа и т.д. придётся править конфиг файлы. Ну и в большом количестве запросов можно потеряться.

2) API - для каждой БД создаёте отдельный хост, к которым подключаетесь со своей админ-веб-морды.
На стороне сайтов пишите скрипты для выборки сообщений, изменения удаления. Данные удобно отдавать в формате [JSON](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.json.php).

Более удобный вариант. На управляющем хосте Вам нужен только список Ваших API с параметрами доступа.

Comment: спасибо. ваш ответ лучший

Comment: @aa22 а если изначально те самые сообщения писать в некую 4ую бд, и там их обрабатывать?

Comment: namak7, нужно, чтобы пользователи с разных сайтов писали сообщения, и я потом мог их обрабатывать и отвечать на них через другой сайт, при этом чтоб у меня все сообщения отображались и мои ответы отображались у них на сайтах.
Сначала я так и хотел 4-ю бд сделать, но это нужно, чтобы содержимое ее отображелось и у них на сайтах